# Hover box and change triangle on top

Tags: html, css

I have a box with a triangle directly on top. Both are colored the same but upon hovering the box, the triangle's color remains without changing.

How can I change the color of the triangle?
[enter link description here][1]

```css
.vw-post-box-read-more {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    background-color: #393939;
    /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);*/
}
.vw-post-box-read-more .triangle {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    border-color: transparent transparent #393939 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
<a class="vw-post-box-read-more" href="">
    <span>Read More</span>
    <i class="vw-icon icon-iconic-right-circle"></i>
</a>
```

EDIT: Sebastian Olsen helped me, thank you

Comment: Sorry I have edited it. Basically I have the .triangle ontop of the read more box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to style the triangle as if it was a child of `vw-post-box-read-more`

Try this code:

```css
.vw-post-box-read-more {
  line-height: 1em;
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #393939;
  /*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);*/
}
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  border-color: transparent transparent #393939 transparent;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.hover-box:hover > .vw-post-box-read-more {
  background-color: red;
}

.hover-box:hover > .triangle {
  border-color: transparent transparent red transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-box">
<div class="triangle"></div>
<a class="vw-post-box-read-more" href="">
  <span>Read More</span>
  <i class="vw-icon icon-iconic-right-circle"></i>
</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I didn't add the hover css yet. I need to hover over the .vw-post-box-read-more and upon doing so, change the color of the triangle.

Comment: I've made an edit. The solution is simple: Wrap your code in a container and select the elements when you hover over that container.